# Visual Studio remote debug Surface RT not working

Tags: visual-studio, arm, remote-debugging, surface

I have a Surface RT (1st generation) with Windows 8.1.
On my Desktop PC i'm working on an App that should run on Windows 8.1 ARM.
Now i wanted to install it to my surface to test it, but it does not work. What i tried till now:

1)
Desktop: VS 2015 Enterprise Update 3 Surface: VS 2015 Remotetools ARM
there is no Update 3 version for VS2015 and ARM and it says i should use the first release of the debug tool: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwJf2.jpg)
I found an update 3 arm version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OO6v.jpg) but it says it is incompatible with my Windows version.

The problem is, after i deployed to my remote device i'm asked for username and password, the surface remote debug tool says it is connected and next i get this error:

> DEP4300: Der Stammordner für App-Paket
>   534e8ba7-f730-492b-926f-5bfb8a63ab43|VS.Debug_ARM.NAME|CN=NAME|534e8ba7-f730-492b-926f-5bfb8a63ab43VS.Debug_ARM.NAMEmit
>   dem Ordner für das Basislayout C:\Users\NAME\AppxLayouts konnte nicht
>   generiert werden. Illegales Zeichen im Pfad.

2) Desktop VS enterprise 2013 update 4 Surface Remote tools 2013 Update 4 for ARM

Problem: I get a message A remote operation is taking longer than expected and then it says it couldn't connect to the msvsmon.exe on the device. The exe is running and when i go to the projects settings it find my device. Even when i disable the authentication VS gets the information. So it needs to communicate with that exe, but when i start to deploy, it does not work.

3) notebook VS enterprise 2013 update 5 Surface Remote tools Update 5 for ARM

Same problem as 2)

4) Desktop VS 2015 Community without Updates Surface Remote tools 2015 (without updates)

same as 2 and 3

already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252969/visual-studio-2012-a-remote-operation-is-taking-longer-than-expected) but there is still no connection when i deploy.

I hope you have an solution for my problem. I don't need to debug on my device i just want to install. So if there is any alternative way to get the app on my surface it is welcome, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have no idea why the remote tool no longer works with Surface RT. But here is my solution for a *Test* app:

1. Create the AppPackage in VS (select only ARM architecture)
2. Copy the *Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\Test\AppPackages* folder to your Surface RT.
3. Open the *AppPackages\Test_Version_ARM_Debug_Test* folder and install the Test_Version_ARM_Debug.cer certificate. Atention! Select the follow option: Alle Zertifikate in folgendem Speicher speichern ... click on Durchsuchen... and save the certificate on the folder *Vertrauenswürdige Stammzertifizierungsstellen*.
4. Now open PowerShell as administrator
5. use *add-appxpackage C:\myapp.appx* cmd the App will be installed.

I hope that helps :-)

Comment: Sounds great. I managed to install the app using a different PC and then using the IP address instead of the name. For some reason the name couldn't be resolved, but the ip works. But I'll give your solution a try